# AngularJS: 'Template for directive must have exactly one root element' when using 'th' tag in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement custom `sortBy` directive in order to make columns in html table sortable.

HTML:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
    <sort-by-directive
      ng-repeat="header in headers"
      onsort="onSort"
      sortdir="filterCriteria.sortDir"
      sortedby="filterCriteria.sortedBy"
      sortvalue="{{ header.value }}">{{ header.title }}
    </sort-by-directive>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('mainApp.directives').directive('sortByDirective', function () {

        return {
            templateUrl: 'SortHeaderTemplate',
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                sortdir: '=',
                sortedby: '=',
                sortvalue: '@',
                onsort: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.sort = function () {
                    if (scope.sortedby == scope.sortvalue)
                        scope.sortdir = scope.sortdir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                    else {
                        scope.sortedby = scope.sortvalue;
                        scope.sortdir = 'asc';
                    }
                    scope.onsort(scope.sortedby, scope.sortdir);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Directive Template:

```
<script id="SortHeaderTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
<th ng-click="sort(sortvalue)">
  <span ng-transclude=""></span>
  <span ng-show="sortedby == sortvalue">
    <i ng-class="{true: 'sorting_asc', false: 'sorting_desc'}[sortdir == 'asc']"></i>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="sortedby != sortvalue">
    <i ng-class="{true: 'sorting', false: 'sorting'}[sortdir == 'asc']"></i>
  </span>
</th>
</script>
```

So when I use `th` as root tag of directive template I retrieve an error:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'sortByDirective' must have exactly one root element. SortHeaderTemplate
```

but when I change `th` to `a` or `span` tags everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I expect that the `<th>` is getting melted away at some intermediate point when it is evaluated outside the context of a `<tr>` (put that template into some random part of your webpage to see the `<th>` disappear).

In your position, I would use a `<div>` in the template, change `sort-by-directive` to an 'A' type directive, and use a `<th sort-by-directive>...</th>` as before, *without* `replace: true`.

Comment: `replace: false` woked for me

Comment: can we get it working with replace :true and restrict type E

Answer (score 33):

I've encountered oddities like that with directive and table elements. See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) for example. Try wrapping your template with `div` tag or use `replace:false`.

Comment: Diddo -- `replace: true` was gunk for me.

Comment: +1, changing `replace: true` to `replace: false` worked for me and I didn't even have any `th` `tr` `td` elements in my `html`

Comment: Worked for me using it as a menu with a link like this one: `<li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('mentionList', $event)"><img title="Mentions List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Mentions List</span></a></li>`

Answer (score 23):

This isn't your case, but I had this very same issue because my code had html comments before and after the template markup, like so:

```
<!-- Foo Widget -->
<div class="foo-widget">[...]</div>
<!-- end:: Foo Widget -->
```

I got rid of the comments and voilá - problem solved.

Comment: Yes, this was also my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the craziest Angular issues I've ever encountered. Huge thanks for this!

Answer (score 9):

This error can be also caused by the fact that you need to have a wrapping element for all your tags in the directive's template. Your directive's template can't be only:

```
<nav></nav>
<div></div>
```

It must be:

```
<div>
 <nav></nav>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the wrapper element in my template fixed this for me.  Thanks for the tip ;0

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when I used the `template` property of the directive definition when I should've been using `templateUrl` if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but there is another solution.
I encountered this issue also, and tried all the above solutions with no luck.

turns out, for some weird reason, that this error is thrown also in case there is a typo in the 'templateUrl' - if angular can't find the html file by the given path - you get the same 'must have exactly one root element' error.

so - fixing the templateUrl fixed the error for me.

hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others: this is because your browser ignores the TH before it gets placed inside the table. My prefered way to fix this is to change the directive to an attribute directive and add it to a TH in the table.

Directive looks like this:

```
.directive('sortByDirective', function () {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'SortHeaderTemplate',
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            sortdir: '=',
            sortedby: '=',
            sortvalue: '@',
            onsort: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.sort = function () {
                if (scope.sortedby == scope.sortvalue)
                    scope.sortdir = scope.sortdir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                else {
                    scope.sortedby = scope.sortvalue;
                    scope.sortdir = 'asc';
                }
                scope.onsort(scope.sortedby, scope.sortdir);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Setting it on your page looks like this:

```
<th sort-by-directive
  ng-repeat="header in headers"
  onsort="onSort"
  sortdir="filterCriteria.sortDir"
  sortedby="filterCriteria.sortedBy"
  sortvalue="{{ header.value }}">{{ header.title }}
</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the issue couple of times and most of the times it could be that you are not wrapping your elements under one element like

```
<div>
  <div... </div>
</div>
```

But there was one occasion where you get this error when the template path is not correct. So please check if you are referring to the template correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A more specific case of [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126979/5468384) is when you *think* that you have the correct path to the template while you actually don't: as it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) for the `templateUrl`

> The URL is relative to our `index.html` file

In my case, I have placed my templates directory one level below `index.html`. When I was setting my property to `templateUrl: '../templates/some-form.html'`, the path was relative to the script but not to `index.html`, resulting to the same error.

Answer (score 1):

i encounter the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$compile/tplrt?p0=stockWidget&p1=stock.html.
```

I get around by removing commement at very top of template file.

replace is deprecated with angularjs 1.3 forward, the next release will remove it completely, it's better not to use replace key.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of angular are you using ?

There was a bug for something looking like your problem that was fixed in <strike>1.2.13</strike> 1.3  Beta 1 [commit link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/31c450bcee53d0a3827b7e0a611e9013b2496506)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very old answer and question but I encountered this error and fix it by put my comment inside a div tag.

before:

```
    <!--You commented code-->
      <div>

      </div>
```

after:

```
<div>
    <!--You commented code-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Biljana's answer, when you think that you have the correct path to the template while you actually don't, specifically upper/lowercase differences in dos/mac/unix systems.

My local path:

templateUrl: 'ng/ImageDnd/dropzone.tpl.html',

my real path:

ng/ImageDnD/dropzone.tpl.html

notice the D at the end of AnnotationsDnd.

My Macbook does not complain, but got an error when deploying in Linux.