# Error: $compile:tplrt: Cannot render page after compiling AngularJS with WebStorm on Windows

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, webstorm

I am currently pretty lost where to start searching for the error that I am facing. The same AngularJS project that my colleagues have been working on for quite a while on Macs cannot be compiled correctly on my Windows machine. No idea if windows and mac has anything to do with the error but just in case I am adding this information.
I've checked out the project with SourceTree and opend it with WebStorm.
First `npm install` then `gulp dev` in the terminal of WebStorm and my angularJs-project is beeing compiled without any errors. When then the browser windows with //localhost is beeing opened, the page shows shortly the loading anymation and then stays blank.

In the attached screenshot you can see the output of the console. Any ideas?

AngularJS Version: 1.7.2

NPM Version: 5.6.0

Gulp:
CLI version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1

What could make the difference that the project is running perfectly on other machines but not on mine?

[image: Google Chrome Console]

**[Edit]:**
I have now reanimated my old macbook, checked out the exact same project with source tree, installed webstorm, ran `npm install`, then doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970251/can-i-install-just-gulp-globally) to set up gulp and then running `gulp dev`: The App runs just fine.

On my Windows Laptop I've started all over, deinstalled WebStorm, deinstalled node.js and did the whole set up as described above. Only difference that I need to install node.js manually on Windows to use npm.... same error as described before.

Comment: must be a problem with your app... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373647/angularjs-template-for-directive-must-have-exactly-one-root-element-when-usin for possible solutions

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's why I said, that on other machines the same app runs without problem. Therefore it must be some kind of compilation problem with my set up but I have no clue what it could be.